# Change programs working directory in Linux from nautilus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

I have a program located in /program, I want to execute it in /program when double-clicking it from nautilus not in /home/user.

I know that using the `cd` command will do what I want, but I want it to be as simple as double-clicking the file, because I will make the program public later and I don't want people to use the terminal to open it.

I also got the idea of creating a script that will `cd $PWD` to the program directory then launch it, but I realized that PWD returns `/home/user`.

I will really apreciate your help :)

Comment: Why not chdir in the program?

Comment: 1.  Nautilus is not a common means of launching programs for most users.  2. Trying to prevent people from launching your program from a command line is wrongheaded, pointless, and and unlikely to be successful.  3. If you want to provide for a GUI launcher then write a `.desktop` file, but don't assume that you can or should try to *force* people to use it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think there was some misunderstanding here, I don't want to force people to use nautilus, desktop files or any other  file manager, and I don't want to force them to use the terminal. What I want to do is to set the program working directory to where the program file is located when it is double clicked in any file manager, if the user want to use the terminal he can.

Comment: @stark I did not really understood what you mean, but if you meant changing the working from the source code of the program then how can I get where the program file is located?

Comment: @JohnBollinger actually the `.desktop` file was exactly what I was loking for, thanks.